# BackboneJS - Content Not Loading On Safari Mac

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, safari

I have built a website for a client using backboneJS for the content / front end. Everything works fine on PC any browser and on the Mac firefox but not safari. I don't have a mac so I cannot see what is happening but the client assures me it doesn't work on safari, he tried it on two different setups.

Does anyone know how I can work out what is going on with this?

The domain is: http://blitzautoworx.com.au/

Basically the content doesn't load into the content area (loaded by ajax which can be seen in the console), the pages are all fine however. They just get an empty content box for each of the pages.

Thanks

Comment: Post some code for the page in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being an issue different to this. My www version of the RESTful API wasn't working, it just happened that the safari testers used www and the non-safari users went to the default URL.